# Li absolutely positioned on overflowed ul scrolling on ipad

Tags: html, css

I have an ul with the (first) li position absolute. The ul has an overflow-y, when I scroll down the first li, stays there since its position is absolute.

```
<div>
<ul style="overflow-y:scroll; max-height:80px;">
    <li>CAt 1</li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content1</li></li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content2</li></li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content3</li></li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content4</li></li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content5</li></li>
</ul>    
</div>
```

But when i test this on ipad, all the elements scroll down including the first one.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bermick/u546exof/10/) desribing the situation
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the position relative to the ul's containing div not the ul. That means taking position: relative off the ul and putting it on the div

CSS

```
#listContianer {
    position: relative;
}

#listContianer ul {/* no positioning here */}

#listContainer .fixedList {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 1em;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="listContainer">
<ul style="overflow-y:scroll; max-height:80px;">
    <li class="fixedList">CAt 1</li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content1</li></li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content2</li></li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content3</li></li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content4</li></li>
    <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content5</li></li>
</ul>    
</div>
```

You'll have to re-tweak the top and left values to suit your styling. But make sure you remove any position on the ul

Or try to make the top list item another element that sits directly in the div

```
<div id="listContainer">
    <span class="fixedList">CAt 1</span>
    <ul style="overflow-y:scroll; max-height:80px;">
        <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content1</li></li>
        <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content2</li></li>
        <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content3</li></li>
        <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content4</li></li>
        <li><img src="../adsf.jpg">Content5</li></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

You'd have to give the ul some top-padding so that the new first item isn't covered

```
#listContianer ul {
    top-padding: 2em;
}
```

Comment: so yo mean that the only change will add position:relative to ul parent div? What i want is that the first child of UL stays and the others scrolldown. This is OK in chrome on pc mac ,, but its not working as supposed on ipad

Comment: Not quite. Because your first li is staying put except on the tablet I assume you have position: relative set on the ul in your stylesheet or somewhere. That will need to be removed because the div should be the nearest ancestor which is positioned. Assuming it works that is

Comment: I know!,,, thats what theory says and its correct, and even I test it in Chrome's Device Emulator as iPad, it displays correctly; but in a real ipad (with chrome and safari) it just doesnt work, it scrolls the whole list

Comment: ok @wunth thanks a lot really. I'll give it a try, although i really would liked a solution with the LI inside the UL (since it works on pc, and on ipad emulated on chrome).

Comment: You're welcome and thank you. In addition - this isn't just because an ipad uses two fingers to scroll a frame within the page and one finger to scroll the entire page? Sorry - not an ipad user.